# How to link two authentication methods of firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I have an android application in which user first registers using email id and password. In the login page I have given two options to login one is using the email id and password which was used to register and other is google sign in. But when the user signs in with the google it updates the provider of that user in the firebase user that it was registered using google sign in and now I can not sign in with the help of email and password. Can someone help me how can I link both the authentication methods so that when I login with email and password or using google sign in it accepts both.

Comment: Have you read through the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking) on this? Did you have a specific problem with that?  If so, please edit the question to be clear where you are stuck, showing the code you have that doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson I did what was written in the documentation but it was giving nullpointer exception

Comment: Right, so, on Stack Overflow, you need to show that code with enough detail that anyone can reproduce the problem.  If we can't see what you're doing wrong, then we can't help.